# How to rewrite a code that uses "values-from" syntax to a code that uses the "of" syntax

Tags: netlogo

I need to convert a code from version 3 of netlogo to version 6. Until now everything was going just fine, but I got stuck in a line of code that I couldn't convert. The line is using the `values-from` syntax, and this syntax was replaced by the `of` syntax (https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/transition.html). I tried to convert the code based on this but I get an error.

The code in the version 3 is the following:

```
let list-temp1 values-from aircrafts with [Team != Team-of myself and distance-nowrap myself <= radius][self]
```

Where aircrafts is a `breed` and `Team` is a variable from aircrafts.

The way I translated the code is the following:

```
let list-temp1 of aircrafts with [Team != [Team] of myself and distance-nowrap myself <= radius][self]
```

But I get the following error with this code: OF expected this input to be a reporter block, but got anything instead

I don't know what to do to get this code working. How can I translate it?

Answer (score 1):

The original syntax is unclear what agent attribute is intended to be stored in the list. So the conversion to `of` had no variable to insert. What I think was intended in the original is to create a list of the agents rather than a list of the variable values belonging to the agents. In modern NetLogo, that would look something like:

```
let list-temp1 aircrafts in-radius radius with [Team != [Team] of myself]
```

That would need to be within an `ask aircrafts []` block. Does that do what you want?

I assume Team is an `aircrafts-own` variable and radius is a global variable (though it will work with turtle variable as well). By the way, make sure you have the world settings (on the interface) set without wrapping.

Comment: I tried your code but I get an error message in the `in-radius` call that says "expected command". It's probably because `radius` is an `aircraft-own` variable (I forgot to mention that, sorry). 
Also, in the original, world wraps are setted with true. 
Can you explain to me why in the original code there is the `[self]` in the end of the line?

Comment: I never used NetLogo 3 but my interpretation of the `[self]` at the end is that `[self]` is the entity that is to be put into the list. That's why I think it's intended to be a list of agents, though my construction is actually an agentset rather than a list. The error is because of the brackets, see update.